# Xcode is not linking the debugger to simulator and disconnects after run

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Xcode is behaving weird with one single project I have where if

- A Run on simulator with "Debug executable" **enabled** Xcode will run the app but will not link the debugger and no loges or breakpoints work then directly after run it will show "finished running" and disconnects
- A run with "Debug executable" **disabled** will run the app with debugger and console prints work but no breakpoints working

in case of physical device its the same

This is currently happening on one machine of the team the other machine is working fine yet we are unable to solve the issue knowing it may be from a 3rd party embedded framework

Comment: @matt its disabled and tried it with no luck

Comment: Do you have same project settings on both devices? Especially `Debug Information Format` in the build options. Does it contain dSYM file?

Comment: @dziobaczy checked it and its the same "DWARF with DSYM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of debugging and searching turns out that for some reason on one machine its not working due to some frameworks having "Do not embed" setting while it should be "Embed & Sign" even though it shouldn't be the case as version control should've synced this still no idea how it started on the first place